# Django / Wagtail - Only first page of a parent

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I'm trying to return a list of the latest children within a tree. `RecordPage` can only be added to a specific node, and I want to have a list on the homepage of the "latest" entries added, but return only on `RecordPage` child per parent node.

I tried something like this:

```
return RecordPage.objects.distinct("parent").live().order_by("-first_published_at")[:5]
```

But Django to sad of me saying that the field parent doesn't exist in the model, which makes sense. I can't figure this out from the docs.

Help plz?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `wagtailcore_page` table don't have such field. The only way to know about the parent would be via the `path` or `url_path` but it's going to be ugly.

But before we try to go into the complicated stuff to make it work in just one queries, it can be done in n+1 queries. Given you say that `RecordPage` can only be added to specific nodes, I'll assume those specific nodes are called `RecordIndexPage`. This way, we can query all the `RecordIndexPage` we are interested in, and for each of them, query the latest `RecordPage` with [descendant_of](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.0.1/reference/pages/queryset_reference.html#wagtail.core.query.PageQuerySet.descendant_of), something like this:

```
record_pages = []
for index_page in RecordIndexPage.objects.all():
    record_page = RecordPage.objects \
        .descendant_of(index_page) \
        .live() \
        .order_by('-first_published_at') \
        .first()
    if record_page:
        record_pages.append(record_page)

record_pages = sorted(record_pages, key=lambda page: page.first_published_at, reverse=True)
```

Now if we want to try to do it in a single query, we can probably hack something with `path`. I'll assume all your `RecordPage`s are at the same depth for now because it will make things much simpler.

Note: this is an idea to explore further more than anything else, I haven't tried this code.

```
from django.db.models.functions import Substr

# Path is a string of length `depth` * 4.
# e.g. `0001` is the path of a page at depth 1, `00010003` is the path of a page at depth 2, etc.
path_step = 4

# Given the root page is always at depth 1 and the homepage is a depth 2,
# the `RecordIndexPage`s would be at depth 3.
parent_depth = 3

# Querying.
record_pages = RecordPage.objects \
    .annotate(parent_path=Substr('path', 0, parent_depth * path_step)) \
    .live() \
    .order_by('-first_published_at') \
    .distinct('parent_path')

record_pages = record_pages[:5]
```

Comment: Thanks @LoïcTeixeira, this is awesome I'll try it tonight. Also, tell Clare that Britney is awesome. ;) #exspringloader